# In highcharts, with multi pie charts on small screen, how to prevent data labels got cut off?

Tags: javascript, highcharts, data-visualization

In a small screen, for example cellphone, when you got multi pie charts placed in your plotting area, the pies close to the edge always have data labels cutting out of the screen, especially when the data label is long.

I am thinking of set the `distance` to negative value to 'pull' the label back a bit, but it is really hard to detect if the label is going out of the screen, and how much I should set the negative distance to.

Is there any way we can find out whether the labels are getting cut off? or is there any good way to solve the label cutting off problem?
[image]

As you can see, at the left side, the labels got cut out of the screen.

Updates:
Tried with manupulating `dataLabels.crop` and `datalabels.overflow`, but they could not handle left/right sides well.
Here is the fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/scottszb1987/wnz50cmy/

Comment: Have you concider using datLabels.overflow and dataLabels.crop parameters? I think that by default they should help you avoid this problem with dataLabels. http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#plotOptions.area.dataLabels.overflow
It would be nice if you will be able to show us live example of your issue, like jsFiddle.

Comment: @GrzegorzBlachliński I just had a try with it, the default value of `overflow` and `crop` should have helped with this problem, but seems for a pie chart they could not handle the left/right side well, only top/bottom are handled. Here is my fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/scottszb1987/wnz50cmy/